# NextJS redirect to other page without query params

Tags: next.js, next-router, dynamic-routing

I am able to successfully redirect the user on successful login to the relative dashboard page. However, the URI is pretty polluted in this case `'somedomain.com/v1/internal/salesman/dashboard?name=SomeName&email=someemail&uid=somenumber'`. I was hoping to do something like `redirect(<DashBoard someProps={someProps}/>` instead of polluting the URI. Is it possible to achieve what I want in NextJS?

```
const onSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    const server_path = process.env.SERVER_ADDRESS;
    try{
      const res = await fetch(`${server_path}api/v1/internal/salesman/signin`, {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({email: email.val, password: password.val})
      });
      if(await res.status === 200){
        const data = await res.json();
        router.push({pathname: '/internal/salesman/dashboard', query: {name: data.name, email: data.email, uid: data.uid}});
      }
    } catch(error){
      console.log(error);
    }
    
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the URL path as you've prefer it to be seen using the `as` argument.

[router.push](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerpush)

> ```
> router.push(url, as, options)
> ```
>
> `as`: `UrlObject | String` - Optional decorator for the path that will
> be shown in the browser URL bar. Before Next.js 9.5.3 this was used
> for dynamic routes, check our previous docs to see how it worked.
> Note: when this path differs from the one provided in `href` the
> previous `href`/`as` behavior is used as shown in the previous docs.

```
router.push(
  {
    pathname: '/internal/salesman/dashboard',
    query: {
      name: data.name,
      email: data.email,
      uid: data.uid,
    },
  },
  '/internal/salesman/dashboard',
);
```

If you want to actually redirect then you can use [`router.replace`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerreplace) with the same arguments.